# делал бан в боте на aiogram, но при попытке бана выскакивает ошибка AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'GROUP_ID'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

библиотера aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(is_admin=True)
@dp.message_handler(commands=["ban"])
async def ban(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply("команда должна быть ответом на сообщение")
        return

    await message.bot.delete_message(message.message_id, chat_id=config.GROUP_ID)
    await message.bot.ban_chat_member(chat_id=config.GROUP_ID, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)


    await message.reply_to_message.reply("Пользователь нашей группы, уже не пользователь нашей группы")





ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'GROUP_ID'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "D:\python_progect\venv\config.py", line 85, in ban
    await message.bot.delete_message(chat_id=config.GROUP_ID)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'GROUP_ID'
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Stop polling...
WARNING:aiogram:Goodbye!
```

вот код с полной ошибкой
ошибка выскакивает после попытки бана

Comment: Что такое `config`? Как вы его определили?

Comment: config это токен

Comment: @Мират а какого вы из токена пытаетесь вытащить `GROUP_ID`?

Comment: ои, не так, спасибо за указание